# ESXi 5.1 ghettoVCB stuck at Clone: 10% done

Tags: vmware-esxi, ghettovcb

Trying to run [ghettoVCB](https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8760) for the first time here. I am using a NAS that is set up as a datastore on the host. I did a dry run and it completed without error.

The VM is ~500GB and there is only one on the host that I'm trying to backup.

I proceeded to start the actual backup:

```
./ghettoVCB.sh -m vmname -g ghettoVCB.conf
```

It goes though the config and looks like it's taking off:

```
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - USING GLOBAL GHETTOVCB CONFIGURATION FILE = ghettoVCB.conf
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - VERSION = 2013_01_11_0
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - GHETTOVCB_PID = 17398616
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - VM_BACKUP_VOLUME = /vmfs/volumes/nas2tb-001/esxi4
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - VM_BACKUP_ROTATION_COUNT = 3
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - VM_BACKUP_DIR_NAMING_CONVENTION = 2013-10-24_11-43-18
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - DISK_BACKUP_FORMAT = thin
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - POWER_VM_DOWN_BEFORE_BACKUP = 0
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - ENABLE_HARD_POWER_OFF = 0
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - ITER_TO_WAIT_SHUTDOWN = 4
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - POWER_DOWN_TIMEOUT = 5
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - SNAPSHOT_TIMEOUT = 15
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - LOG_LEVEL = info
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - BACKUP_LOG_OUTPUT = /tmp/ghettoVCB-2013-10-24_11-43-18-17398616.log
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - ENABLE_COMPRESSION = 0
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - VM_SNAPSHOT_MEMORY = 0
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - VM_SNAPSHOT_QUIESCE = 0
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - ALLOW_VMS_WITH_SNAPSHOTS_TO_BE_BACKEDUP = 0
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - VMDK_FILES_TO_BACKUP = all
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - VM_SHUTDOWN_ORDER =
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - VM_STARTUP_ORDER =
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info: CONFIG - EMAIL_LOG = 0
2013-10-24 11:43:19 -- info:
2013-10-24 11:43:22 -- info: Initiate backup for vmname
2013-10-24 11:43:22 -- info: Creating Snapshot "ghettoVCB-snapshot-2013-10-24" for serv2
Destination disk format: VMFS thin-provisioned
Cloning disk '/vmfs/volumes/esxi4-storage/vmname/vmname_1.vmdk'...
Clone: 10% done.
```

and it's been that way for over an hour now. Stuck at `Clone: 10% done.`.

Thing is: I can see the vmdk on the NAS. And it looks like almost the whole thing is there. On the NAS it's showing ~430GB but on vSphere Client > Summary is shows as 507GB. I don't see the vmdk on the NAS growing any more.

The logfile mimics some of the above and is sitting at "Creating Snapshot..." and nothing else is coming in.

- Is the vmdk on the NAS showing all those GB because of the provisioning or something? i.e. is the size of the file not necessarily indicative of the amount of actual data that has been copied?
- <strike>Is there are reason it might be "Stuck" at 10%? i.e. could it really be taking this long?</strike>
- Any other tips?

Thanks.

---

Edit: as soon as I hit the Submit button, I glance over to see that it has incremented to 11% done. Good to know it'll be complete sometime around when the sun explodes.

Comment: Why not use a commercially available product, like Veeam or Trilead or any number of other products that offer both a free and a paid edition?

Comment: Have been looking at veeam. Unfortunately, in the small shop that this is, budgets are...tight I guess you could say. Veeam has trials, but to cover all our infrastructure would be cost-prohibitive at this point which is why I'm seeing if going ghetto would work. Haven't hear of Trilead before though -- will check it out. Thanks!

Comment: Veeam has a free version. Trilead also has a free version. Many other applications have free versions. I'm not trying to hammer on you but are these VM's important to the business? Would the loss of these VM's cause the loss of time, money, productivity, etc.? If so, then they're important enough to justify the expense of a proper backup solution. In todays' business environment, IT assets are critical assets yet they get short shrift and get treated like an ugly stepchild, which never ceases to amaze me.

Comment: Veeam offers a free version, yes. But it doesn't work with ESXi free which is what we're running. Yes these are important VMs. There is file-level backups running right now, but I want to capture the VM's for DR. I agree with your points whole-heartedly. I'm not the one that needs convincing. But at the same time, I'm not the one with the checkbook. I keep bringing it up and I keep trying to convince them. In the meantime, I'm trying to figure something out. Trilead doesn't mention free ESXi so I'm dloading now to try. Thx.

Comment: I'm not aware that Veeam free edition doesn't support the free edition of vSphere. Where are you seeing that information? The only "real" difference I've seen is that scheduled backups aren't available in the free editions of Veeam and Trilead. Also, I'm in complete understanding of your financial position. I just wish the people that hold the purse strings would wake up already. They have insurance for everything else related to the business but they won't pay for proper DR/BC components for the IT assets.

Comment: Conveniently, they don't tell you until you register/log in and go to the download page: "Note: Free vSphere Hypervisor (free ESXi) is not supported. vSphere Essentials or higher license level required." Yup, and I'm sure it'll be MY fault when it hits the fan and it takes 2 days to get back up running.

Comment: Ok, in that case Trilead doesn't have that limitation. I find Trilead to be less complex and cumbersome than Veeam. The paid version of Trilead is only $760.00 US - http://www.trilead.com/editions/

Comment: Thanks again. Seems to be a good solution. If you can add an answer I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Trilead VM Explorer](http://www.trilead.com) runs $760.00 US and supports both vSphere (the free edition as well) and Hyper-V. It features scheduled backups and file level as well as VM level restores.

Comment: I don't want to be the bad guy here, but for me this is not even close to an answer for the question. You provide nothing towards solving the problem at hand.

Comment: 6.5 years too late I'm afraid.

Comment: You know what they say, better late than never. ;)
I got a similar issue right now actually if you like to way in there: https://serverfault.com/questions/1001936/ubuntu-18-04-vm-freezes-and-kills-single-esxi-when-cloning-disk

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old question, but my problem was not reading the available [documentation](https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8760) for ghettoVCB/being a noob at setting up NFS. If you are using NFS as your target datastore, make sure your NFS export is set to use 'async'. Additionally, you can set "DISK_BACKUP_FORMAT = 2gbsparse" (as opposed to 'thin', etc.) in your ghettoVCB config, which will consume less space (only used space) on your destination datastore.

My NFS transfers to my DNS-323 NAS device running Alt-F were going *very* slowly -- ~140 KB/s. At that rate, it would've taken about 2 days just to back up a single smallish VM. After setting async I'm now getting 6-8000 KB/s on a single 1G link and my backups just took about 20 mins.

Note that this is my home "for fun" ESXi installation/backup infrastructure, and like everyone else here is saying -- for commercial use I'd really recommend purchasing something that's going to be easier to maintain and obtain support for.

Comment: Thanks for the information -- didn't know about async option. Curious why you felt the need to downvote the question?

Comment: ...4 years later: according to my votes tab, I've never voted on anything

Comment: Ah ok.  Sorry for being presumptuous.